# Равномерность разделения массива на части случайного размера

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Вопрос возник из обсуждения [ответов на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591648) на ruSO.

Сам я давно с теорией вероятности не сталкивался и времени сейчас особо нет вспоминать, но может быть кому задачка покажется интересной.

Есть массив значений. Надо разделить его на 4 части случайного размера. Был предложен нижеследующий алгоритм:

1. Запускаем цикл из 3-х итераций
2. В каждой итерации откусываем от начала исходного массива случайное количество элементов (но так, чтоб хотя бы по одному элементу остальным итерациям осталось)
3. Последний кусок берем целиком

Собственно возникло сомнение, что распределение количества элементов на большом числе попыток будет неравномерным. В первом будет больше чем во втором и т.д.

**UPD** Экспериментально получается такая картина (100 элементов, 1.000.000 прогонов)

```
0:48.53718
1:24.66839
2:12.88542
3:13.90901
```

Вопрос такой. Какова будет математическая формула расчета этого распределения на бесконечном количестве попыток? (обратите особое внимание на последнее значение)

Comment: Конечно для первого куска больше шансов быть больше остальных.

Comment: Для него всегда доступен диапазон от 1 до сумма - кол-во элементов. Для остальных он может быть короче.

Comment: Этот вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591648/

Comment: Псевдокод банален, получаем пять точек: `0 < Random(0, Lenght) < Random(0, Lenght) < Random(0, Lenght) < Lenght`. Как вы будете откусывать куски по полученным индексам, дело реализации.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian см. пункт 2. Если первые три куска будут содержать по одному элементу, то последний будет содержать весь теоретически доступный первому куску диапазон.

Comment: Вот именно что если. Но чаще всего ему будет доступен диапазон меньше, чем первому.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian зато для последующих частей будет больше вероятность отхватить кусок больше, чем у предыдущих, так как диапазон разброса случайного количества уменьшается. Собственно про то и вопрос. Теория вероятностей такая интересная штука, что "очевидные" вещи не всегда являются правильными.

Comment: Почему для последующих вероятность отхватить большой кусок выше?

Comment: Ну вот у вас кстати экспериментально и получилось, что первые части больше. В пропорции каждый следующий кусок в два раза меньше предыдущего, начиная с 0.5 (не считая последнего, который равен предпоследнему).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ну вот смотрите, на первом куске длина 100, вероятность выбрать любое значение 1/100. Допустим 20 выпало. Тогда во втором куске вероятность выбрать любого числа из диапазона 0..80 уже 1/80

Comment: Ну не любого, а от 0 до 80. Т.е. от 80 до 100 уже не доступны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно многие отметили, тут размер каждой следующей части зависит от предыдущей.

**Расчет распределения на бесконечном количестве попыток (для приведенного в вопросе алгоритма)**

`c` - количество элементов первоначального массива

`g` - количество групп, на которые надо разбивать

G<sub>1</sub>..G<sub>n</sub> - количество элементов в n-ной группе

Так как случайная выборка из диапазона при бесконечном числе попыток дает нам нормальное распределение, следовательно можем принять, что результат будет сходиться к его пику, то есть `G=c/2`

Следовательно, G<sub>1</sub>=(c-g)/2, G<sub>2</sub>=(c-G<sub>1</sub>-g+1)/2

Раскроем для G<sub>3</sub>:

G<sub>3</sub>=(c-(c-(c-g)/2-g+1)/2-g+2)/2

для простоты примем `a=c-g+n`

G<sub>n</sub>=(2<sup>n-1</sup>*(a-1)-2<sup>n-2</sup>*(a-2)-...-2<sup>n-n</sup>(a-n))/2<sup>n</sup>

G<sub>n</sub>=(a*(2<sup>n-1</sup>-2<sup>n-2</sup>-...-2<sup>n-n</sup>)-2<sup>n-1</sup>+2*2<sup>n-2</sup>+...+n*2<sup>n-n</sup>)/2<sup>n</sup>

Членов со степенями ровно `n`, следовательно для `n=1` имеем вырожденный случай:

**n=1**

**G<sub>1</sub>=(c-g+1)/2**

**n>1**

так как 2<sup>n-1</sup>+2<sup>n-2</sup>+...+2<sup>n-n</sup>=2<sup>n</sup>-1

G<sub>n</sub>=(c-g+n-2<sup>n-1</sup>+2*2<sup>n-2</sup>+3*2<sup>n-3</sup>...n*2<sup>n-n</sup>)<sub>/2<sup>n</sup></sub>

G<sub>n</sub>=(c-g+n-2<sup>n-1</sup>+2*2<sup>n-2</sup>+3*2<sup>n-3</sup>...n*2<sup>n-n</sup>)<sub>/2<sup>n</sup></sub>

**n=g**

Тут особый случай, в соответствии с условиями задачи.

G<sub>g</sub>=c-(G<sub>g-1</sub>+..+G<sub>1</sub>)

**Проверяем для `g=4` и `c=100`**

G<sub>1</sub>=48.5

G<sub>2</sub>=24.5

G<sub>3</sub>=12.75

G<sub>4</sub>=14.25

Comment: Только для G1 = (c-(g-1))/2

Comment: @YuryBakharev да, правильно. Когда нижние/верхние индексы форматировал единичку потерял. Расчет то с ней делал. :)

Comment: @YuryBakharev еще бы вот этот ряд с `2*2^(n-2)+...+n*2^(n-n)` как-=то человечески записать. Но уж всю математику позабыл :(

Comment: я тоже подзабыл линейку. Но по большому счету запрограммировать его довольно таки легко, на свой вопрос вы ответили.

Answer (score 2):

Если у нас есть **n** элементов и их надо разбить на **k** групп не нарушая порядка - то задача сводится к выбору индексов первых элементов во всех группах кроме первой. То есть общее число разбиений - **C(n-1, k-1)** = **(n-1)! / (k-1)!(n-k)!**.

При этом вероятность того, что в первой группе будет **m** элементов, равна **C(n-m-1, k-2) / C(n-1, k-1)**. А значит, длину первой группы можно получить следующим образом:

1. генерируем случайное число от **1** до **C(n-1, k-1)**
2. Если оно не превосходит **C(n-1-1, k-2)** - значит, длина будет 1. Иначе, вычитаем из него **C(n-1-1, k-2)**.
3. Если оно не превосходит **C(n-2-1, k-2)** - значит, длина будет 2. Иначе, вычитаем из него **C(n-2-1, k-2)**.
4. Если оно не превосходит **C(n-4-1, k-2)** - значит, длина будет 1. Иначе, вычитаем из него **C(n-4-1, k-2)**.

и т.д.

---

Если же выбирать длину первой группы равномерно - то ее средняя длина окажется равной **(n-3)/2** - в то время как правильная средняя длина группы равна **n/k**. То есть при k=4 "глупый" алгоритм будет генерировать первую группу в среднем асимптотически в 2 раза больше чем надо, за счет остальных.

Answer (score 0):

По условию допускается, что у нас УЖЕ ЕСТЬ случайный алгоритм! Мы имеем набор зависимых событий, если принять что кол-во элементов в массиве X, то вероятность события "выбора разного числа  элементов" будет 1/x, и выбор второго куска будет такой же(даже с учетом того что нужно оставить 3 элемента на остальные куски), только в случае если в первом событие произойдет выбор 1 элемента(вероятность такого события - 1/x)во всех остальных случая диапазон последующего выбора будет меньше! Все это справедливо от X>4

Comment: Очень интересно прочитать, что не понравилось?

Comment: Лучше здесь не спрашивать почему минусуют ) Будет только хуже. Как на хабре.

Comment: Не вижу ни одного здравого комментария!

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вранье. Ни тут, на на хабре "за спрос" не наказывают.

Comment: *"вероятность события "выбора разного числа элементов" будет 1/x"* - непонятно что имеется в виду.

Comment: ПРИМЕР: X= 10, В первое событие можно выбрать 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 и вероятность каждого выбора будет около 0,14 (1/7 возможных событий), так вот вероятность выбора второго куска с равной длинной будет уже Y*0,14!!!! ИТД!!!!

Comment: Автор вопроса, тебе не интересно, что единственно правильный ответ на твой вопрос минусуют?

Comment: @YuryBakharev, какой эмоциональный... прекратите писать капсом и флудить знаками препинания. Как минимум, после такого неуважения, Ваши комментарии с ответом вообще проигнорируют.

Comment: @Alex Krass Про стилистику записи - понял, я тут недавно. Извиняюсь. А почему ответ то должны проигнорировать?

Comment: Надо собачку (@) и имя пользователя добавлять, если хотите, чтобы он обратил внимание на комментарий.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian я отвечал автору, вроде бы как он в любом случае видит, а остальные комментарии я не знаю кому адресовать.

Comment: @YuryBakharev вслед за общим впечатлением, люди тут предпочитают в большинстве деловой уровень общения. Ну и да, есть некоторые проблемы с минусами "просто так", но в большинстве случаев это поправимо.

Comment: Затрудняюсь сказать, может и так. Мне казалось, что комментарий по умолчанию видит только автор вопроса или ответа к которому он был оставлен. В вашем случае - ответ ваш.